# How to convert grpc_channel_credentials to ChannelCredentials

Tags: c++, grpc

when I try to convert  grpc_channel_credentials object to ChannelCredentials, I have to use SecureChannelCredentials as a bridge, but `SecureChannelCredentials` comes from `./src/cpp/client/secure_credentials.h`, and type-defined in `./include/grpcpp/security/credentials.h`, so I code as below;

```
grpc_channel_credentials* creds = grpc_tls_credentials_create(options);
    return std::shared_ptr<grpc::ChannelCredentials>(
            new ::grpc::SecureChannelCredentials(std::move(creds)));
```

However, compilation failed due to:

```
/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/xxxx.cc: In function ‘std::shared_ptr<grpc_impl::ChannelCredentials> grpc::sgx::TlsCredentials(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*)’:
/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/xxxx.cc:233:55: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘grpc::SecureChannelCredentials {aka class grpc_impl::SecureChannelCredentials}’
             new ::grpc::SecureChannelCredentials(creds));
...

/usr/local/include/grpcpp/support/channel_arguments_impl.h:38:7: note: forward declaration of ‘grpc::SecureChannelCredentials {aka class grpc_impl::SecureChannelCredentials}’
 class SecureChannelCredentials;
```

Thanks a billion if you can give me any tips to fix this!

Comment: GRPC Version: 1.31

Comment: The translation doing the `new` needs the definition of `SecureChannelCredentials`, not just a declaration. What are your includes?

Comment: @Caleth  had 
 included https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.31.x/include/grpcpp/security/credentials.h#L30

Comment: Yes, that only provides a declaration, not a definition. If the definintion of `SecureChannelCredentials` is not anywhere in `include/grpcpp`, then it is likely you are not meant to instantiate it. Should you instead be calling `grpc::experimental::TlsCredentials`?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, actually  I make it work [here](https://github.com/bytedance/fedlearner/pull/860/commits/d3956cb6f031b37cd175be489afdda81c28c90c8#diff-c4bee591949e14e6ca3c4ed5fed740c8e4a9ecadb9859f9daee441580e8ada4eR257) with client cert offered .  but I try to let the server skip the client cert verification like I did under GRPC 1.38.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Caleth  1.31 failed when I pass nullptr to key materials and credential reload config  due to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.31.x/src/core/lib/security/credentials/tls/tls_credentials.cc#L43

Comment: if I skip the sanity check here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.31.x/src/core/lib/security/credentials/tls/tls_credentials.cc#L114, everything works well. Can I do that?

Comment: "I try to convert grpc_channel_credentials object to ChannelCredentials" Your approach is wrong, you shouldn't be touching these details. `grpc::experimental::TlsCredentialsOptions opts; /*fill opts*/ auto creds = grpc::experimental::TlsCredentials(opts);` is what you should be doing to get credentials

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as Caleth already pointed out, grpc_channel_credentials is the detail that you shouldn't be worried about too much. Just establish grpc::experimental::TlsCredentialsOptions and put it into grpc::experimental::TlsCredentials.
The server side currently doesn't support skipping certificate verification. We are working to make that happen, and the ongoing work is https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/25631.

Comment: How if I use the GRPC_TLS_SKIP_ALL_SERVER_VERIFICATION  for the current release?  I skipped the sanity check for the client-side, and it seems work.

Comment: Yes, you can use that, but just make sure you understand the implication behind it. Setting that field without additional peer checks would leave your applications to man-in-the-middle attacks. Normally we don't recommend that in productions.